# Magento order status not changing to complete

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

We have a strange issue in our Magento shop. When an order is placed he is getting the right status processing, but when we book the shipment he is not changing to complete and is keeping the order status processing.

Does anyone know how this can happen?

Answer (score 1):

Do you create an invoice? Every order must have an invoice before you see the status "complete".

Comment: Yes we do, that is the strange thing. We make an invoice, make a shipment, but the order status does not change